Can "exchange A for B" mean gaining A?

Mill is particularly concerned that minority opinions should not be silenced just because they are held by very few people. Unfashionable ideas have potential value for the whole of humanity, even if only held by one person:

If all mankind minus one were of one opinion, mankind would be no more justified in silencing that one person than he, if he had the power, would be justified in silencing mankind.

His reason is this. If the view is correct, then humanity misses the opportunity to exchange truth for error. If, however, the view is misguided, then we forfeit an opportunity to reinforce truth through its collision with error. Every opinion has value for us either because it is true, or else because, though false, it reinforces the truth and contributes to its emergence. (Nigel Warburton, Free Speech: A Very Short Introduction, 2009, pp. 25-26; bold is mine)

I have learned the phrase "exchange A for B" as giving up A and gaining B as in, say, the sentence "You can exchange your currency for dollars in the hotel".
But in the passage I quoted, it seems that "exchange truth for error" should mean otherwise given the context. That is, it should mean giving up error and gaining truth.
Can "exchange A for B" mean gaining A (and giving up B)? Or Am I missing something?

as you can see, it can ... you have to use the overall context to determine the actual meaning

I would say that 'exchange' in that piece has the meaning 'transpose two things', rather than 'give up something to gain something else. As @jsotola says, the directionality is implied by context and/or common sense.

I'd say no such ambiguity arises with change A to B, which imho always means you started with A, and ended up with B. But if you use exchange rather than change, and/or use a different preposition (such as for, with) you're completely dependent on context to resolve potential ambiguity.  So my advice is stick with change and to.

Can "exchange A for B" mean gaining A (and giving up B)? Yes, and it does here. I don't see any reason to provide long convoluted explanations.

Thank you for all your answers. it's very helpful. Initially I asked Chat GPT. GPT said 'no, or at least not naturally'. I was confused and so came here to ask native people. Now GPT is not all that reliable even in learning english.

'Now GPT is not all that reliable even in learning english. –  Clean93' - you did not need that 'even'.

Remember that ChatGPT is more intelligent than a traditional search engine, but should still be treated as an avenue to follow, not as the final solution. When I ask anything of ChatGPT it is because I can instigate a conversation about what I am looking for, to refine the answer.

@Clean93 And you think you would get a  correct answer on ELL. ?

It just means that "error" and "truth" swap positions. In context it clearly means that mankind could gain "truth" in place of "error".

Good thought. I slightly prefer this over the (also plausible) explanation that it's a slip. One possible subtle motivation for the slip is that this is almost identical to a famous Pauline phrase in Romans 1 (where it means what it sounds like, being a condensation of the exchangers).

I. Exchange of Ideas Doesn't Imply Give and Take:
In the context of the marketplace of ideas, OP has asked:

Can "exchange A for B" mean gaining A (and giving up B)?

The verb, "exchange"
has two meanings:


To give or return something to someone and receive something from them:
Example: Under these schemes, shareholdings can be exchanged for units in a unit trust.
To communicate with someone who then replies:
Example: We exchanged a few words before the meeting began.


When discussing ideas, exchange aligns more closely with the second meaning. It does not imply giving something up to gain something else, as it might in a literal transaction. Instead, it represents a dynamic interaction where:

One can gain without losing: In an exchange of ideas, individuals can acquire new knowledge, perspectives, or truths without necessarily abandoning their own beliefs or ideas.
Non-transactional nature: Unlike a traditional exchange involving trade, the "exchange of ideas" fosters growth and learning without requiring a direct trade-off.

This understanding aligns with the metaphor of a "marketplace of ideas," where the goal is the mutual sharing and refinement of knowledge, rather than a simple swap.
John Stuart Mill, in On Liberty, uses the metaphor of a  "marketplace of ideas" to advocate for free speech. He argues that allowing all opinions to be expressed enables society to challenge error and uncover truth, much like goods are examined and refined in a market. Nigel Warburton references this metaphor in Chapter 2, titled "A Free Market in Ideas," of his book Free Speech: A Very Short Introduction, to emphasize the importance of open dialogue for societal progress.
Mill explains that:

If a minority opinion is correct, society benefits by replacing false beliefs with true ones.
If the opinion is erroneous, debating it strengthens the understanding and justification of the true opinion.

By comparing free speech to a marketplace, Mill underscores the dynamic process where ideas compete, ensuring that truth emerges and prevails through open discussion and critical examination.

I am reproducing this for whoever gave me a downvote. Please do your homework properly. - One often hears the expression "the marketplace of ideas" used in reference to John Stuart Mill's political theory in On Liberty. 1 This metaphor describes a situation in which people speak and exchange ideas freely, and it has a certain plausibility on two counts.
